# How to insert data from html table to database using laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, html-table, insert

I have a large html table with 2 columns representing product code and amount. how can insert this into database using laravel.
table looks like this (9k rows...)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create array of all the records and the just do

```
    $your_arr = [
            [
                'column_1' => 'TU24Dc',
                'column_2' => 2
            ],

            [
                'column_1' => 'TU83',
                'column_2' => 2
            ],

            [
                'column_1' => 'TU81',
                'column_2' => 2
            ],
        ];

 DB::table('table_name')->insert($your_record_arr);
```

Or With Eloquent Model

```
Model::insert($your_record_arr);
```